# Should I write total values to the database or calculate them when needed?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a number of tables which are in a cascading relation, i.e. `projects` references `clients`, and `tasks` references `projects`. There are certain columns in a `task` which will need to be added to a total in the referenced `project`.

Should I have an extra `total` column in `projects`, and update its value each time there is a change in `tasks`? Or should I calculate the total whenever it is needed at output? What if I need a total of the totals for a `client`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a general answer can be given to this question.  If you have a need for totals at the project level you will need to evaluate if it's worth creating a column just for that.

It could probably be done fairly easily with a calculated column.

Keep in mind that this will take up more space on your db and possibly slow down Insert/Update/Delete operations. On the other hand it would also potentially speed up certain select operations.

You will need to take a look at what your needs are and decide if these trade offs are worth it.

Personally, if I wasn't seeing performance problems and the SQL wasn't too ugly I would probably just calculate when needed.